# How frequently is upvoting YouTube comments allowed?

Tags: youtube

Is it a one time thing or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a limit, I don't think it's publicly available. There does seem to be some sort of delay going on after a while after voting frequently then seeing whether the up-vote count on the most up-voted answer for a few videos changes.

As compared to Stack Exchange limit of 5 seconds there does seem to be as harsh limit (if any limit even exists).